# quest for online tutorials on CNN backprop

Tags: cnn, backpropagation

I'm looking for video or text tutorial materials on CNN backprop that show how weights (convolutional kernels and last layer weights) are trained. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one good material: https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199

This one also might help: https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/convolution_layer.html (it also has other useful materials).